# How to setup 52°North WPS with GRASS backend under Windows and Linux?

Tags: grass-gis, wps, 52north

I followed tutorials [TutorialBackendGRASSWin](https://wiki.52north.org/Geoprocessing/TutorialBackendGRASSWin) and [TutorialBackendWpsGRASSLinux](https://wiki.52north.org/Geoprocessing/TutorialBackendWpsGRASSLinux) to setup 52°North WPS with GRASS backend under Windows and Linux (CentOS7), but result of GetCapabilities request does not contain any GRASS algorithms.

My configuration is

```
GISRC_Dir   D:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.2.0\.grassrc72
Grass_Home  D:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.2.0
ModuleStarter_Home   D:\Programs\wps-grass-bridge\gms
Python_Home   D:\Program Files\Python2.7.9
Python_Path   D:\Program Files\Python2.7.9
TMP_Dir  D:\Programs\tmp\grass_tmp
```

and under linux:

```
GISRC_Dir   /home/houzw/.grass7/rc
Grass_Home  /usr/lib64/grass74
ModuleStarter_Home  /opt/soft/wps-grass-bridge/gms/
Python_Home  /usr/bin/
Python_Path   /usr/bin/python2.7
TMP_Dir  /home/houzw/tmp/grass_tmp
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: does the log file show anything?

Comment: @IanTurton  No GRASS related logs, just INFO about registers of  Generator, Parser and LocalAlgorithmRepository algorithms

Comment: I have found the problem:
In webadmin page index.jsp, width of checkbox to activate algoritms repository is set to 0, so unless to disable the inline style, it's impossible to active the repository
the version of wps is 3.6.1/3.6.2